# Home Wifi or DNS is dropping / ignore every 2nd request to any website

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, router, dns

So my home LAN is a mix of Wifi and cables.

The deskop pc's that are wired network connections -> no problems at all.

My wifi connections are failing to connect to any website 50% of the time. I refresh the page and it starts to work.

Using Chrome, it takes a long time to wait for the page until it says 'Takes to long to load'. Hmm. ok .. and then it auto refreshes and boom, page loads!

Ok - this 'feels' like it's either:
- A DNS issue for the LAN
- A DNS issue for my computer.

This problem occurs on my Windows 10 laptop AND on my wife's macbook pro. So that's fair to suggest that it's not specific to *my* computer only. Also, when I'm at work on the work Wifi, there's 100% no problems at all.

So it's something to do with my home config.

First thing's first -> change the DNS primary/secondary on the Modem/Router. Did that, rebooted, same issue.

Purge the Chrome DNS settings -> also did that, same issue.

Manually change my Wifi network settings:
- 192.168.0.whatever / 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.0.1
- DNS 1.1.1.1 / 8.8.8.8

Still - same thing happens.

Modem/Router is a Fritz!Box 3790.

I'm sorta stuck trying to figure out how to replicate this problem. I'm hoping someone might suggest some tricks to use / software to install to snoop traffic to see what's going on?

Comment: when you notice that a page is not loading, do a cli dig/nslookup to the site you are trying to connect - this might show you if there is a DNS issue. if you use chrome you can open the network tool (ctrl+shift+i, select network, hit refresh)

Comment: If wired systems worked well - have you done a site survey for wireless? Something like wifiman for android would give you an idea of where weakspots are and/or what channels are busy

Comment: @JourneymanGeek is your suggestion that the problem is that _physical_ location is causing the issue? vs .. software or hardware?

Comment: based on the information its plausible. I've had an *interesting* time getting wireless reliable in my apartment and it seems like a worthwhile course of investigation

Comment: kewl - i'll give this a go. no android devices at home. just mac, iphone/ipad, windows - any recommendations?